# How do I iterate over the product of different lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

I have the following problem:

I have a list `l1` and I want to iterate over the product with the function `itertools.product`, I also want to include the second list `l2` in the same way.

For example:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in list(itertools.product(l1, repeat = 2)):
    print(i)
```

The output is:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
...
```

I think this is very clear. But how can I manage to include the second list and get an output like this:

```
(1, a),(1, a)
(1, a),(2, b)
(1, a),(3, c)
(1, a),(4, d)

(2, b),(1, a)
(2, b),(2, b)
(2, b),(3, c)
(2, b),(4, d)

(3, c),(1, a)
(3, c),(2, b)
(3, c),(3, c)
(3, c),(4, d)

(4, d),(1, a)
(4, d),(2, b)
(4, d),(3, c)
(4, d),(4, d)
```

I know that a proper solution would be to combine for-loops. But that doesn't fit for me as I want to increase the `repeat`-counter.

Answer (score 3):

By providing a `zip` of the lists to `product`:

```
for i in product(zip(l1,l2), repeat = 2):
    print(i)
```

Wrapping in a `list` isn't required, the for loop takes care of calling `next` on the iterator for you.

If you want a new-line for every 4 combinations, use `enumerate` (starting from `1`) and add a `\n` when `c % 4` is `0`:

```
for c, i in enumerate(product(zip(l1,l2), repeat = 2), 1):
    print(i, '\n' if c % 4 == 0 else '')
```

Output:

```
((1, 'a'), (1, 'a')) 
((1, 'a'), (2, 'b')) 
((1, 'a'), (3, 'c')) 
((1, 'a'), (4, 'd')) 

((2, 'b'), (1, 'a')) 
((2, 'b'), (2, 'b')) 
((2, 'b'), (3, 'c')) 
((2, 'b'), (4, 'd')) 

((3, 'c'), (1, 'a')) 
((3, 'c'), (2, 'b')) 
((3, 'c'), (3, 'c')) 
((3, 'c'), (4, 'd')) 

((4, 'd'), (1, 'a')) 
((4, 'd'), (2, 'b')) 
((4, 'd'), (3, 'c')) 
((4, 'd'), (4, 'd'))
```